# Pagination algorithm: display ranked search results for unique eCommerce merchants

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, pagination

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I am building a search functionality for an eCommerce website and looking for the most *optimal* **Pagination algorithm** that satisfies several requirements.

When a user submits a search product query on our site, we return a list of products scored according to their specified preferences. Search results are then presented over several web pages. Because multiple listings can belong to the same merchant, we want to ensure that a merchant does not dominate the results in a single page.

1. Results are sorted by **descending** order of score.
2. Given the number of **results per page**, we divide the result set into separate pages (**paginate**) while having a merchant appear at most once on each page.
3. If a page cannot be filled with only unique merchants, ***then*** the page is padded with the remaining product entries while preserving the **initial ordering**.

For example:
    // results to display per page
    let numPerPage = 4;

```
// results array of csv, comma-delimited strings with format:
// merchant_id,listing_id,score,description

let results = [
 "5,90,500.1,description text",  
 "4,51,495.8,description text",  
 "8,72,490,description text",  
 "5,89,485.4,description text",
 "5,80,480,description text",
 "9,18,478.1,description text",  
 "6,50,475.9,description text",  
 "5,56,472,description text",  
 "7,12,470.5,description text",  
 "5,5,465,description text",
 "6,10,450,description text"
]

// Paginate function output: array of strings representing paginated results, 
// with an empty String separator after each page, except the last page.
let output = [
 "5,90,500.1,description text",  
 "4,51,495.8,description text",  
 "8,72,490,description text", 
 "9,18,478.1,description text",
 "", // this is a page separator
 "5,89,485.4,description text",
 "6,50,475.9,description text",  
 "7,12,470.5,description text",
 "6,10,450,description text",
 "", // this is a page separator
 "5,80,480,description text",
 "5,56,472,description text",  
 "5,5,465,description text"]
```

The following code has been written so far:

```
function paginate(numPerPage, results) {
 // first map : transform into array of arrays
 // second map : transform into array of objects w/ key-value pairs
 let hash = {};
 let output = [];
 output = results.map(listing => listing.split(',')).map((listing, i) => {
    return {
      "index": i,
      "merchant_id": listing[0],
      "listing_id": listing[1],
      "score": listing[2],
      "description": listing[3]
    }
  });
  // sort the listings by descending score.
  output = output.sort((a,b) => b.score-a.score);
  console.log(output);
 // next, create a hash of merchant: array of listings
 // while results per page < numPerPage ...
 // ... optimal pagination algorithm in progress..
 }
```

I'm thinking of creating a hash of `"merchant": [array of that merchant's listings]`, and `shift()` the first value of the merchant arrays as we progress. But the algorithm gets interesting when into account **unique** merchant preference per page requirement. In addition, the algorithm I came up wasn't very optimal.

Would truly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solved with a combination of set and Map

```
key - MerchantId, 
value - PriorityQueue of type MerchantListingDetails
```

Here Priority Queue is max heap based on score.

MerchantListingDetails class consists of following-
merchant_id,
listing_id,
score,
description

```
1. Initially your Set & Map is empty. 
2. for each MerchantListingDetails // from input line 
   check if merchantID is present in set, 
    if not then add it to set and append to page1.
    if merchantId present in set, then add the merchantId and corresponding object to Map.
3. Continue till your page is full.

Now for page2 :
1. Delete all the entries from set.
2. copy the keys(merchantId's) from Map to set.
3. for each entry from Map,
     get the first entry for each merchant and display it on page.
     if the merchant has no entries left in map , delete its key from map and set.
4. If the page has required list of output, then again go to step 1 for new page and continue.
```

Note: This is just a rough algorithm i could think of in 10 min. Let me know how you implemented it.